# I need to know regarding this question related to prefix sum

Tags: javascript

```js
var subarraySum = function(nums, k) {
  let obj = {
    0: 1
  };
  let count = 0;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += nums[i];
    if (obj[sum - k]) {
      count += obj[sum - k];
    }
    obj[sum] = ++obj[sum] || 1;
  }


  return count;
};

console.log(subarraySum([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3], 4))
console.log(subarraySum([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3], 5))
```

Question statement: Given an array of integers nums and an integer k, return the total number of subarrays whose sum equals to k. A subarray is a contiguous non-empty sequence of elements within an array.

Why did we define obj as {0 : 1}?
And what exactly is happening when you write obj[sum-k]?

Comment: Are you giving us your homework to do ? 

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions before posting your homework on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

More comments in the code. First I simplified some statements meant to confuse. Then we are left with the pure algorithm. The idea is keeping a `total` and all the totals we have so far as "seen before". If at any point we find current total to be "seen before" + `k` it means we found a total `k` sub group

```js
var subarraySum = function(nums, k) {

  // obj counts true or false for *every* sum we accomulate
  let obj = {
    0: 1
  };
  
  let count = 0;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

    sum += nums[i];
    
    // if we encounter a seen before difference between sum and k
    // it means we have a "sum-k subgroup" thus far.
    // example: 
    // consider we encounterd 1, 2, 3, 4 so we encounterd 10, right?
    // we keep going then we a point of sum 15
    // it means we must have since the last 10 found a subgroup of sum 5
    if (obj[sum - k]) {
    
      // so we found one
      count++
    }
    
    // mark current sum as encountered = true
    obj[sum] = 1;

  }
  return count;
};

console.log(subarraySum([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3], 5))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```